Не получается создать дополнительную кнопку (InlineKeyboardButton) в sendInvoice reply_markup
Пытался отправить сообщение с оплатой и кнопкой назад но выдает ошибку, подскажите пожалуйста что я неправильно делаю и возможно ли вообще это реализовать ?
Вот код
@dp.message(Command("start"))
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    builder = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
    builder.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Pay", pay=True))
    builder.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Нажми меня",callback_data="random_value"))
    PRICE = types.LabeledPrice(label='Настоящая Машина Времени', amount=4200*100)
    await bot.send_invoice(message.chat.id,
                           title="***",
                           description="***",
                           provider_token=PAYMENTS_TOKEN,
                           currency="kzt",
                           photo_url="***",
                           photo_width=416,
                           photo_height=234,
                           photo_size=416,
                           is_flexible=False,
                           prices=[PRICE],
                           start_parameter="one-month-subscription",
                           payload="test-invoice-payload",
                           reply_markup=builder)

И ошибка
ERROR:aiogram.event:Cause exception while process update id=111006418 by bot id=6464477035
ValidationError: 1 validation error for SendInvoice
reply_markup
  Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of InlineKeyboardMarkup [type=model_type, input_value=<aiogram.utils.keyboard.I...bject at 0x700e031d7790>, input_type=InlineKeyboardBuilder]

 Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of InlineKeyboardMarkup [type=model_type, input_value=<aiogram.utils.keyboard.I...bject at 0x700e031d7790>, input_type=InlineKeyboardBuilder]


Билдер сам по себе не является клавиатурой. Поэтому в аргументе reply_markup нужно передавать builder.as_markup()
Код:
await bot.send_invoice(...,
                       reply_markup=builder.as_markup())

Это преобразует объект builder в объект клавиатуры
